# Matlab histogram plotting two separate datasets with the same PDF, different colors

Tags: matlab, histogram, probability-distribution

I have two vectors, one is ~10x larger than the other. I'm trying to represent both on a probability distribution function histogram where each vector has a different color, but the PDF applies to the entire dataset...

If I use histogram(data), the output is in counts which is appropriately proportional. However, if I specify PDF normalization as below, both are scaled to their individual normalizations.

How can I plot all data as one single PDF, but maintain the colors?

Here is mock code:

```
% sample data
dist1 = normrnd(-2,1, [1, 750]); % Inthws vector
dist2 = normrnd(2,1, [1, 12000]); % Pchws vector

% Create histogram with dist1 in red
hold on
histogram(dist1, 'Normalization', 'pdf')

% Create histogram with dist2 in blue
histogram(dist2, 'Normalization', 'pdf')

% Add legend and axis labels
legend('dist1', 'dist2')
xlabel('Data values')
ylabel('Frequency or count')
hold off
```

Comment: So you want to add the two histograms? Maybe draw them as a stacked bar chart?

Comment: first [`histcounts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) on separate data, then `bar` them in same figure.

Comment: _each vector has a different color, but the PDF applies to the entire dataset_ So you want each histogram to be normalized to the full data set, so that the sum of thw two areas is 1?